# How can I solve the errors in Miktex console compilation?

Tags: miktex, console

I have the following errors while trying to compile my .tex file in console mode:
"entering extended mode
<C:\Users\Documents\myfile.tex>
Latex2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
!Undefined control sequence
1.2\section
Does this mean that my .tex file just has errors?
What commands should I do to get pdf file from the console?

```
For example,the following code compiles correctly
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{First document}
\author{Lucy \thanks{Me}}
\date{11th of August}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

In this document some extra packages and parameters
were added. There is an encoding package
and pagesize and fontsize parameters.

\end{document}
```

But the russian library addition makes a mistake

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}


\title{First document}
\author{Lucy \thanks{Me}}
\date{11th of August}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

In this document some extra packages and parameters
were added. There is an encoding package
and pagesize and fontsize parameters.
\selectlanguage{russian}
Привет
\end{document}
```

And here is the code that did work correctly using the pdflatex console:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}      
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{datatool} %for database
\usepackage{markdown} %for .txt data


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}

\input{Parameters}
\input{Title}

\tableofcontents


\input{first_section}           % here is the addition .tex file
\input{second_section}           
\end{document}
```

And my log file says the following:

```
Pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTex, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 <MiKTeX 22.3> <preloaded format = pdflatex.fmt>
Restricted \write18 enabled.
Entering extended mode
<C:/Users/ B/Documents/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
<C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
<C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo>>
<C:\ Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
========================================================================
Unfortunately, the package Cyrillic could not be installed.
Please check the log file:
C:\Users\  B  \AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
========================================================================

Package foentenc Error: Encoding file ‘t2aenc.def’ not found.
<fontenc>       You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H<return> for immediate help.
…
l.111 \ProcessOptions*
```

Comment: Running (La)TeX from the console or from a text editor does not make a difference. Clearly you have errors in your TeX file. Quite likely the macro `\sequence` hasn't been defined.

Comment: Thanks, @campa, your comment makes sense. Suddenly I made the mistake in question description. Now I've edited it. The miktex console app should know the \section macro. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on the `\documentclass` and the packages you use whether `\section` is defined or not. It should be defined in most document classes, but it is hard to tell without having a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that (1) you are not copy-pasting the error code but are re-typing it, and you misspelled `l.2` for `1.2`, and thus (2) you have a `\section` macro on line 2 of some file which you are trying to compile, implying that (3) you are quite likely trying to compile a file without `\documentclass` (probably a file you want to `\input` somewhere). But alas, that's only my crystal ball.

Comment: @campa, your crystal ball is geniously right and I was typing the error, not copypasting. But as I understood some LaTex libraries did not install automatically. For example with different languages. And I even cannot just put the path to the pdflatex console for my project made in Overleaf

Comment: Thanks, @JasperHabicht, I've added my code and example, that works

Comment: Sorry but I still cannot understand what you are doing. In your last comment you talk now about Overleaf. while the question is tagged MikTeX. As I said, the form of the error message suggests that you are trying to run TeX on either `first_section.tex` or `second_section.tex` but that's only a guess...

Comment: show the complete (!) log-file of the second document (the one that fails).